# How to set precision for json_real while doing json_dump using jansson library

Tags: json, double, jansson

If a double value of 8.13 is passed into json_real and dump the json i see that its printing 8.1300000000000008, Is there any way to get 8.13 or 8.13000000000000000 exactly in C?

```
    double test = 8.13;
    json_t* msgtest = json_object();
    json_object_set_new(msgtest, "test", json_real(test));
    char* msgStr;
    msgStr = json_dumps(msgtest, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON_REAL_PRECISION](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref.html?#encoding), introduced in jansson 2.7.

> Output all real numbers with at most n digits of precision. The valid
> range for n is between 0 and 31 (inclusive), and other values result
> in an undefined behavior.
>
> By default, the precision is 17, to correctly and losslessly encode
> all IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <jansson.h>

int main() {
    double test = 8.13;
    json_t* msgtest = json_object();
    json_object_set_new(msgtest, "test", json_real(test));
    printf("%s\n", json_dumps(msgtest, JSON_REAL_PRECISION(3)));
}
```

It prints

```
{"test": 8.13}
```